# replace missing values in a 3d array

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imputation

I have a 3d array containing missing values:

```
arr = np.array([[[ 1, 13],[ 2, 14],[ 3, np.nan]],[[ 4, 16],[ 5, 17],[ 6, 18]],[[ np.nan, 19],[ 8, 20],[ 9, 21]],[[10, 22],[11, 23],[12, np.nan]]])
```

I would like to perform imputation to replace those missing values, preferably using nearest neighbors. I tried looking into `sklearn.impute` module but none of the functions accept a 3d array. I know I could flatten the array, but that will result in loss of spatial information. Are there any alternatives?

EDIT:
The array has a 3d spatial configuration and in the real world might look like this:

```
        layer 2
        13  14  nan
        16  17  18
        19  20  21
        22  23  nan
layer 1
1   2   3
4   5   6
nan 8   9
10  11  12
```

for example, value `1` is a neighbor of `2` and `4` in layer 1.

By flattening `arr`,

```
   [[ 1, 13],
    [ 2, 14],
    [ 3, np.nan],
    [ 4, 16],
    [ 5, 17],
    [ 6, 18],
    [ np.nan, 19],
    [ 8, 20],
    [ 9, 21],
    [10, 22],
    [11, 23],
    [12, np.nan]]
```

it looks as though `4` is farther away from `1` than `2` is, but it isn't. `1` is just as close to `2` as it is to `4`, just in different dimensions.

Comment: Is there any evidence that a flattened array will result in loss of spatial information? You can see a nice counter-example of image classification with 1d arrays [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html) which falsifies your claim.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @afsharov. I'm just thinking in the actual configuration of the array in physical space, in that removing a dimension necessarily entails losing some information about space. I have updated my question.